# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: while getting information out of the database

Tags: php, pdo

Getting an error while trying to get data out of a database based on id which i got from i button on a previous page. When i echo the id only it gives me the correct id but in the full query it gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound'
>   in

I found some SO answers on this but none of them solved the problem i had.

```
<?php
$fetch_article_info = $db->query("select * from news_article where id = :id");
   $fetch_article_info->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
$list = $fetch_article_info->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

Here are some of my public funtions in db.class which i think might be usefull

```
class Database{

private $host = DB_HOST;
private $user = DB_USER;
private $pass = DB_PASS;
private $dbname = DB_NAME;
// database handler
private $dbh;
private $error;

private $stmt;


public function __construct(){
    // Set DSN
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    // Create a new PDO instanace
    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    }
    // Catch any errors
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
    if (is_null($type)) {
     switch (true) {
       case is_int($value):
         $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
         break;
       case is_bool($value):
         $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
         break;
       case is_null($value):
         $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
         break;
       default:
         $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
     }
   }
   $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}
public function query($query){
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }

    public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function resultset(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

Comment: Change `query` into `prepare` call, you prepare a statement with placeholders, then execute it with parameters. `$fetch_article_info = $db->prepare("select * from news_article where id = :id");`

Comment: @Fracsi Thanks for your reply tried that before getting Warning: PDO::prepare(): SQLSTATE[00000]: No error: PDO constructor was not called when i use prepare

Comment: Your error states the problem, your parameter isn't binding correctly.

Comment: do understand what u copied? or u just copied the class?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing into your execute function. See below.

```
$db->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
$list = $db->resultset(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($list);

// db.php file
public function execute($params){
    return $this->stmt->execute($params);
}

public function resultset(){
   // $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: He's running query, you don't have to run execute.

Comment: Tested on my local.  Works for me after changing his code.